# sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier loop for max_depth

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am currently running a basic scikit-learn decision tree using the below code:

```
tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10)

tree = tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is there a way to test multiple values of `max_depth` (e.g. between 10 and 15) without doing this individually, i.e. with a loop? I am not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you’d find this useful: [GridSearch](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Other than GridSearch, they also have RandomSearch. I believe there are also different libraries that do hyperparameters optimisation.

Basically what they do is you give them your model and a set of hyperparameters to test, and they give back the results.

You’d do it by

```
    params = { max_depth : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]}
    gs = GridSearchCV(tree, params)

    gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then you can see the results in `gs.cv_results_`

Comment: I guess you meant: `params = { "max_depth" : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]}`

Comment: Let me add, that, usually, we want the best parameters which can be obtained by: `print(gs.best_params_)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
for depth in [5, 10, 15, 20, 50]:
    tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=depth)

    tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(f'Depth: {depth}. Score: {tree.score(X_train, y_train)}')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. As a 3k+ rep user, you should already be aware of this.